# Cant write Data to Firestore using React Native and Gifted Chats

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implment a Chat functionality in my React Native App.

The Problem i am facing is, that if i send a message it doesnt get saved in the Firestore Database. But if i remove the useLayoutEffect Function, the Messages get Saved in Firestore.
Ive got the code from this [Page](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-chat-app-react-native-gifted-chat/):

Here is my Code:

```
import React, {useCallback, useLayoutEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {addDoc, collection, query, orderBy, onSnapshot} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {db} from '../../../firebase';
import {GiftedChat} from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

export const EventChatScreen = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'chats');
    const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));

    return onSnapshot(q, QuerySnapshot =>
    {
        setMessages(
            QuerySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ // these key:value pairs are in a required format for GiftedChat
                _id:       doc.data()._id,
                createdAt: doc.data().createdAt.toDate(),
                text:      doc.data().text,
                user:      doc.data().user
            }))
        );
    });
}, []);

const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {
    setMessages(previousMessages =>
        GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages)
    );
    const { _id, createdAt, text, user } = messages[0];
    addDoc(collection(db, 'chats'), {
        _id,
        createdAt,
        text,
        user
    });
}, []);

return (

    <GiftedChat
        messages={messages}
        showAvatarForEveryMessage={true}
        onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
        user={{
            _id: 1,
            avatar: 'https://i.pravatar.cc/300'
        }}
    />
    );
    }

export default EventChatScreen
```

As i mentioned before. As soon as i remove the useLayoutEffect it saves the Data to Firebase.
Ive also tried to get the Return Value of the Add Doc. But as soon as the useLayoutEffect function is added, it doesnt return a Value.

**EDIT:** Now it works while i am in the Debug Mode.